# how to get all static members of a class in C#?

Tags: c#, static-members

How can I get all static members of a class in c#? I know I can access one like this class1.member1 but I am looking for a way to get all members. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var members = typeof(class1).GetMembers(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
```

(feel free to add `NonPublic` if you want...)

If you want to *get the value* of a member, you need to know the member type - either via `.MemberType`, or by checking the *concrete* type (via `is`, etc). Properties are `PropertyInfo`, for example, and have a `GetValue()` method that you can pass a `null` to as the target (`obj`) for a static property. Fields (`FieldInfo`) work similarly.